# Which algorithm is efficient for finding a pattern in a permutation?

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I am currently trying to create a program to generate pattern-avoiding permutations. In order to do that I must test a permutation for the inclusion of a pattern.
A pattern is defined as a sub-permutation of a longer permutation. A permutation includes a pattern if there exists a subsequence in that permutation that is ordered exactly as the pattern is. E.g. the permutation (51234) includes the pattern (123) since there exist the subsequences (234), (123), (134), (124) in the longer permutation. For the pattern (123) I could adapt the Longest Common Subsequence algorithm, but for other patterns such as (231) for example, it doesn't seem to work anymore. Are you aware of any algorithm which could be suitable to test for the existence of a pattern in a permutation?

Comment: This sounds like [Knuth–Morris–Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)?

Comment: Hmm, I think that the problem is that the subpattern does not have to be adjacent. E.g. (15243) contains the pattern (123) as well

Comment: I think the question needs more information. When you say "permutation", I think you're really talking about a particular representation of a permutation: perhaps a list of sequences such that each number 1..n appears in exactly one sequence? And a "pattern" appears in this representation if it's a subsequence of one of the sequences?

Comment: (123), (231) and (312) each describe the exact same permutation, but judging from your question the pattern (123) appears only in the first. Is that right?

Comment: @PaulHankin: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_pattern. Multiplex, that WP article has an impressive number of references, some of which concern computational complexity. so you might consider checking it out

Comment: Wow, how could I have missed that ... Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @rici thanks! I was confused because the question looks like it's using the cycle-based permutation syntax because of the brackets, ie: (123) represents the permutation 1->2->3->1, but I think it's really it's the permutation 1->1, 2->2, 3->3.